# Filter an Object Array and set to state Array variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the JSON Input that I am going to filter by orderId and then set to the state variable.

```
[{"orderId":3,"userId":3,"firstName":"Amal","lastName":"kankanige","contactNo":"011-3456787","status":"pending","deliveryAddress":"No:24/c,Anders Road,Wijerama,Wijerama,Srilanka","productName":"Apple","quantity":2,"total":100.0,"id":null,"order_date":"2019-01-31 10:28:29"}]
```

this is my state.

```
  this.state = {
      merchentOrders: [],
      filterMerchentOrders: []
    }
```

//this is the method

when I am filtering by orderId it's successfully working and then I want to set the filtered output to " `this.setState({filterMerchentOrders: filterMerchentOrdersX});`". when I console out the state as below the values are not set.

```
getOrderDetails = id => {

    console.log("id ==" ,id);

    let filterMerchentOrdersX = this.state.merchentOrders.filter(value => {
      return (
        value.orderId.toString()
          .indexOf(id) !== -1

      );
    });         

    this.setState({filterMerchentOrders: filterMerchentOrdersX});

   //this is working  

     console.log("filterMerchentOrdersX ==" ,filterMerchentOrdersX);       

   //this gives an empty array  

      console.log("this.state.filterMerchentOrders ==" ,this.state.filterMerchentOrders);
  };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Perharps try this:
`setState(
  { filterMerchentOrdersX },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);`

Comment: without `state`? `this.filterMerchentOrders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the reason that `setState` runs asynchronusly, when you `console.log` the value state might not be updated.

To view the state after it updates, you can pass a callback function.

```
this.setState({filterMerchentOrders: filterMerchentOrdersX},()=>{
   console.log("this.state.filterMerchentOrders ==" ,this.state.filterMerchentOrders);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you've written console.log() immediately after setState method, since setState is an async method an at the time java script runs your console.log it will be showing you the previous state in which obviously array is not set, for this you should put your console in the second argument of setState that is a callback function.

```
this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.files[0]},()=>console.log(this.state));
```

or you can simply user async await.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the ES6 syntax, your function could be shorter and neater. But it seems to me that you're not doing anything wrong

```js
getOrderDetails = id => {
    const filterMerchentOrders = this.state.merchentOrders.filter(
     value => value.orderId.toString().indexOf(id) !== -1
    );
    this.setState({filterMerchentOrders});
}
```